# Angular Material component not working: 'mat-option' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to add angular material component. but the component did not work properly. that error said

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-option' is not a known element:
// ...
```

I think the error comes from `app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component'; 
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MyFormComponent } from './my-form/my-form.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    PostsComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    DetailsComponent,
    FooterComponent, MyFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule,HttpClientModule,MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule,MatFormFieldModule
  ]
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to import `MatSelectModule` cause `mat-option` are declared inside this module and add this into the `AppModule` imports

```
import { ..., MatSelectModule, ... } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
   imports: [ ..., MatSelectModule, ...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: done. now error said "ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(27,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MaterialModule'."

Comment: In my code I have no `MaterialModule` - I have `MatSelectModule`

Comment: MatFormField.html:1 ERROR Error: Found the synthetic property @transitionMessages. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application. what is this >?

Comment: This means if you use animations you need to add module `BrowserAnimationsModule`

Comment: Adding MatSelectModule worked in Angular material 9.2.4. :)

Comment: In Angular 10, it's `import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import **`MatSelectModule`**,

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    //..Other modules here
],
```

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name 'MaterialModule'.
any

Comment: you are missing related modules for browser and material

Comment: @user1177842 why did you remove the answer?

Comment: i did not remove

Comment: i see it as removed :P

Answer (score 1):

Actually you also need to add `MatOptionModule` not just `MatSelectModule`.

```
imports: [
  ...
  MatSelectModule,
  MatOptionModule,
  ...
],
```

Otherwise you may encounter problems when setting the `value` of your `mat-option`.

Answer (score 1):

I amazed that none of the answers given by the user is correct, how I knew that?
is because i faced the same problem by myself.

the solution is to import
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';

and write in import
MatSelectModule

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **MatSelectModule** in AppModule.ts

```
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that most people make a **custom component** which they then add to **"shared.module.ts"**
In this case, you should pay attention to what **you need to import into the custom component itself**

**custom-select.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { CustomSelectComponent } from './custom-select.component';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CustomSelectComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, MatSelectModule, FormsModule],
  exports: [CustomSelectComponent, MatInputModule],
})
export class CustomSelectModule {}
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomSelectModule } from './components/customSelect/custom-select.module';
import { DatePipe } from './pipes/date.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ]
  imports: [
    ...
    
    M̶a̶t̶S̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶M̶o̶d̶u̶l̶e̶,̶,
    CustomSelectModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    M̶a̶t̶S̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶M̶o̶d̶u̶l̶e̶,
    CustomSelectModule,
    ...
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```